# Logical arguments in user defined functions in r

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a function in r that includes a named argument with three options. (What I want to do is find the area in the right tail of a normal curve, the left tail, or both tails.) Is this possible? I've come up with this, but I get an error when I try it with `right=BOTH`.

```
st.pnorm<-function(x,µ,ø,right=c('TRUE','FALSE','BOTH')){  
  if (right==FALSE) return({pnorm((x-µ)/ø)})  
  if (right==TRUE) return({1-(pnorm((x-µ)/ø))})  
  if (right==BOTH) return({x*2})  
}
```

> st.pnorm(19.4,11,8.4,right='BOTH')
>  
>   Error in st.pnorm(19.4, 11, 8.4, right = "BOTH") : 
>    object 'BOTH' not found

(I know x*2 isn't correct, but I want to see if I can get this to work structurally before I actually write that code.)

Comment: 'TRUE' is not logical and is not the same as TRUE, but it can be coerced to TRUE. Ditto for 'FALSE', but NOT for "BOTH".

Comment: `identical("TRUE", TRUE) #[1] FALSE`

Comment: I think you've got a good answer to the technical question. Practically, when you're doing weird things like mix booleans and strings, I think it's a good indication to do it differently. Your function code might be clearer and more straightforward if instead of `right `you named your agument, say, `tails`, and it had options `"left"`, `"right"`, or `"both"`. In isolation, `right = "BOTH"` doesn't make much sense, the only reason it's in caps is because TRUE and FALSE are caps when booleans and not strings...

Comment: Sorry I'm so late on this, but this was all v v helpful, thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

```
st.pnorm<-function(x,µ,ø,right=TRUE){  
     if (right==FALSE) return({pnorm((x-µ)/ø)})  
     if (right==TRUE) return({1-(pnorm((x-µ)/ø))})  
     if (right=="BOTH") return({x*2})  
 }
```

`TRUE` and `FALSE` should be enclosed in quotes while `BOTH` does need to be, hence `if (right=="BOTH")`. Also with `right=TRUE` you are declaring a default value to the `TRUE`.

***EDIT***

As @KonradRudolph points out in the comments,  the `if` statement is checking if, what is inside the brackets, is `TRUE` or not. If it is `TRUE` then it will action otherwise it will skip. Therefore as `right` takes on `TRUE` or `FALSE` the above could be re written as the following:

```
st.pnorm<-function(x,µ,ø,right=TRUE){  
     if (!right) return({pnorm((x-µ)/ø)})  
     if (right) return({1-(pnorm((x-µ)/ø))})  
     if (right=="BOTH") return({x*2})  
 }
```

Where `!` acts as the not operator.

Comment: If `right` is going to be logical then `==TRUE` is redundant. The if statement checks the logical value and continues if it is true. So `if (right) return(..)` and `if(!right) return(..` instead.

Comment: Well yeah I know, but it better to be verbose in an answer than simply remove it.

Comment: @amwill04 No, it’s not. You’re perpetuating a mistake, you should be correcting it.

Comment: its not a mistake though, it may not be the most efficient way of writing the code but it will make sense when someone reads it.

Comment: @amwill04 It is a mistake that relies on a flawed understanding of boolean logic. It happens to work but that doesn’t make it not a mistake.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'll concede that I probably should have edited to take that into account but it certainly doe not rely only a flawed understanding of boolean logic. The mistake in the code is that I am checking if something is `TRUE` twice.

Answer (score 1):

That your named argument has three options suggests that strings (as you've set it up) are a better way to go than Boolean values. Calling the parameter **tail**, instead of **right**, would make your intent clearer.

```
st.pnorm<-function(x,µ,ø,tail=c('right','left','both')){  
  if (tail=='left') return({pnorm((x-µ)/ø)})  
  if (tail=='right') return({1-(pnorm((x-µ)/ø))})  
  if (tail=='both') return({x*2})  
}
```